# Prevent TAB from landing on a CheckBoxTableCell<> in JavaFX 8

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

I have a TableView in JavaFX 8, which is editable.  One of the fields is a CheckBoxTableCell.

I have noticed that the TAB key lands on the first CheckBoxTableCell in the grid and gets stuck there.  I don't want this behavior.  I like to navigate to the cell with the keyboard and activate with the SPACE.  However I need tab to ignore this field - since it gets stuck.

I tried the following:

```
booleanColumn.setCellFactory (to -> {
   CheckBoxTableCell<DTO, Boolean> cell = CheckBoxTableCell<>();
   cell.setFocusTraversable(false);
   return cell;
}
```

This however has no affect on the focus of the field, since it's editable, it lands on that control and gets stuck.

If I change to:

```
cell.setDisable(true);
```

Then TAB will skip the field, but I can land on the column with the arrow keys.  However I can't select the checkbox with the mouse.

I am at a loss as what to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The workaround to get the `TAB` key working first implies consuming the event so the default `TableView` traversal engine doesn't process it, and selecting the next or previous cell instead.

This will move the selection from cell to cell:

```
table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

table.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
    switch (keyEvent.getCode()){
        case TAB: {
            keyEvent.consume();
            if (keyEvent.isShiftDown()) {
                personTable.getSelectionModel().selectPrevious();
            } else {
                personTable.getSelectionModel().selectNext();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

But it won't be enough to get the `CheckBox` focused, and the `space` key can't be used to select it. So a second step is required to move the focus from the selected cell to the inner checkbox.

When the cell gets the focus, its node will request it.

```
booleanColumn.setCellFactory (param -> {
    CheckBoxTableCell<DTO, Boolean> cell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
    cell.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
        if (nv && cell.getGraphic() != null) {
            cell.getGraphic().requestFocus();
        }
    });
    return cell;
});
```

Notice you can't have both the cell and it's checkbox focused at the same time, so the cell will appear grey (selected but not focused), unless you modify its css.

Comment: Thanks @Jose, however this solution will not work for my needs unfortunately.  With many controls on the screen then I need to have tab navigate the controls.  We are using the arrow keys to navigate the table, and listen to keystrokes to start editing.  When I implement this fix, I lose the navigation from control to control.   Shift Tab also stops at the first cell in the row, it doesn't appear to move up to the previous row.  I would really like to just prevent the CheckBoxTableCell from getting focus.  I have handled the space key activation to select it when the cell has focus.

Comment: You can still use the tab key to navigate your controls, only when the table gets the focus it will used to navigate the cells. If you don't consume the tab event, you can still use the arrow keys to navigate the cells.

Comment: I what you suggested and it doesn't allow focus to traverse to the next control on the screen.  Do you have a suggestion for that?  When I remove the consume on the event, then SHIFT + TAB takes me to the previous control when on the last row, but it won't take me to the next control. I am finding the behavior a little odd.  Most tables don't have CheckBoxTableCells, so I'd prefer a consistent behavior with arrow keys, rather than tab.  I will see about skipping the control manually, unless you have a better way?

Comment: To prevent focus on the checkbox I capture the tab/shift tab and manually jump to the next control.  This seems a little clunk as I would have assumed cell.setFocusTraversable(false) would have worked.  Thanks for the suggestion.